# Why am I getting this JS error?

Tags: jquery, html, debugging, syntax

This is the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
d.d.extend.globalEvaljquery-1.5.1.min.js:16
d.ajaxSetup.converters.text scriptjquery-1.5.1.min.js:16
bQjquery-1.5.1.min.js:16
vjquery-1.5.1.min.js:16
d.support.ajax.d.ajaxTransport.send.c
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
$("div#notif_js").html(' ');

$("div#notification_box").html('<div class="notification">
  <p><img alt="Justin meltzer" class="feed_image_notif" src="/system/photos/46/tiny/Justin Meltzer.jpeg?1303109121" /> JMeltz 
   added a comment to <b>second</b> by <img alt="Justin meltzer" class="feed_image_notif" src="/system/photos/45/tiny/Justin Meltzer.jpeg?1303109101" /> Justin Meltzer</p>
  <a href="/videos/506"></a>
</div>
<div class="notification">
  <p><img alt="Justin meltzer" class="feed_image_notif" src="/system/photos/46/tiny/Justin Meltzer.jpeg?1303109121" /> JMeltz 
   added a comment to <b>second</b> by <img alt="Justin meltzer" class="feed_image_notif" src="/system/photos/45/tiny/Justin Meltzer.jpeg?1303109101" /> Justin Meltzer</p>
  <a href="/videos/506"></a>
</div>
<div class="notification">
  <p><img alt="Justin meltzer" class="feed_image_notif" src="/system/photos/46/tiny/Justin Meltzer.jpeg?1303109121" /> JMeltz 
   added a comment to <b>second</b> by <img alt="Justin meltzer" class="feed_image_notif" src="/system/photos/45/tiny/Justin Meltzer.jpeg?1303109101" /> Justin Meltzer</p>
  <a href="/videos/506"></a>
</div>
<div class="notification">
  <p><img alt="Justin meltzer" class="feed_image_notif" src="/system/photos/46/tiny/Justin Meltzer.jpeg?1303109121" /> JMeltz upvoted bhbu </p>
   <a href="/videos/505"></a>  
</div>      
<div class="notification">
  <p class= "all_notifications">All Notifications</p>
  <a href="/videos/notification_go"></a>
</div>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't allow you to have multiple lines inside of your strings.  You either need to convert each line into a \n, like so:

```
$("div#notification_box").html('line1\nline2');
```

or precede the end of each line with a '\' like so:

```
$("div#notification_box").html('line1\
line2');
```

The first method seems to be more commonly used, although the second method looks better in my opinion.

Also, a nice and easy way to check for javascript errors is to run it through a javascript delinter such as http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php or http://www.jslint.com/ (although jslint doesn't report the error as nicely as javascriptline).

---

Comment: How would I do this if I'm using embedded Ruby that is converted into html?

Comment: If the html is in a variable, you can use a string replacement function to replace all occurrences of '\n' with '\\n'.  I'm not a ruby man myself so I'm not sure what the function would be.

Comment: After some research, it seems that you could use myhtml = myhtml.gsub(/[\n]/, "\\n") to replace all the newlines, but that assumes that the html is in a variable named myhtml.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me using jQuery 1.5.2+

http://jsfiddle.net/XSAb2/

**EDIT:** I've converted the string into a single line string because I thought it was just StackOverflow formatting that forced the multiple lines

Comment: yeah, it's not one line for me, but I'm not sure how to fix it because it's embedded ruby being converted to html

Comment: I'm not sure about how ruby works, can you show us the embedded ruby code?